# Replacing view data with edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basic profile view comes from `index.cs.asp?Process=ViewB_Profile`. 

When users click on `<a href="index.cs.asp?Process=EditB_Profile">edit profile</a>`, dialog box opens to edit the basic profile.
But I want the edit form to replace basic profile view data.
How can I do it, is there a plugin for it?

Thank you very much!

edited!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(function V_Basic_Profile() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content/profile/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewB_Profile",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#B_Profile").append(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#B_Profile").append('.');
            }
        });
    });
    $(function E_Basic_Profile() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "content/profile/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewB_Profile",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#B_Profile").append(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#B_Profile").append('.');
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be fairly trivial to toggle two different divs in jQuery:

```
<div id="profile">
...
</div>
<form id="profileForm">
...
</form>

<script>
// ...
success: {
    $('#profileForm').html(data).show();
    $('#profile').hide();
}
// ...
</script>
```

**Edit: Try this**

```
<div id="profile_view">Loading...</div>
<div id="profile_form" style="display:none; ">Loading...</div>

<a href="javascript:loadProfileForm()">Edit Profile</a>

<script>
function loadProfileView()
{
    $.get("content/profile/index.cs.asp?Process=ViewB_Profile", function(html) {
        $('#profile_view').html(html).show();
        $('#profile_form').hide();
    });
}
function loadProfileForm()
{
    $.get("content/profile/index.cs.asp?Process=EditB_Profile", function(html) {
        $('#profile_form').html(html).show();
        $('#profile_view').hide();
    });
}
$(loadProfileView);
</script>
```

Comment: That's fine.  Just populate the form html in your AJAX success handler, then toggle the profile data div and the form.

Comment: Do I need to put it between `$(document).ready(function() { ` and `});`? Because its not triggered right now.